# What does the variable $this mean in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, this

I see the variable `$this` in PHP all the time and I have no idea what it's used for. I've never personally used it.

Can someone tell me how the variable `$this` works in PHP?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

It's a reference to the current object, it's most commonly used in object oriented code.

- Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
- Primer: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Object-Oriented-Programming-with-PHP.html

Example:

```
<?php
class Person {
    public $name;

    function __construct( $name ) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
};

$jack = new Person('Jack');
echo $jack->name;
```

This stores the 'Jack' string as a property of the object created.

Comment: Saw similar example code in the KillerPHP OOP tutorial :)
http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/php-objects-page-1/

Comment: Nice and easy explanation. @meder omuraliev

Comment: why cant you just call `$name` from inside the class and need to use `$this`?

Comment: @S.W.G. `$this->name` is saying grab the name property of this class. `$name` is saying use a variable called `$name`. So that's why our __construct passes $name as a variable and sets `$this->name = $name`. We're saying set the value of our name inside of this object equal to the value we passed in as `$name`.

Answer (score 47):

### The best way to learn about the `$this` variable in PHP is to try it against the interpreter in various contexts:

```
print isset($this);              //true,   $this exists
print gettype($this);            //Object, $this is an object 
print is_array($this);           //false,  $this isn't an array
print get_object_vars($this);    //true,   $this's variables are an array
print is_object($this);          //true,   $this is still an object
print get_class($this);          //YourProject\YourFile\YourClass
print get_parent_class($this);   //YourBundle\YourStuff\YourParentClass
print gettype($this->container); //object
print_r($this);                  //delicious data dump of $this
print $this->yourvariable        //access $this variable with ->
```

So the `$this` pseudo-variable has the Current Object's method's and properties.  Such a thing is useful because it lets you access all member variables and member methods inside the class.  For example:

```
Class Dog{
    public $my_member_variable;                             //member variable

    function normal_method_inside_Dog() {                   //member method

        //Assign data to member variable from inside the member method
        $this->my_member_variable = "whatever";

        //Get data from member variable from inside the member method.
        print $this->my_member_variable;
    }
}
```

`$this` is reference to a PHP `Object` that was created by the interpreter for you, that contains an array of variables.

If you call `$this` inside a normal method in a normal class, `$this` returns the Object (the class) to which that method belongs.

It's possible for `$this` to be undefined if the context has no parent Object.

php.net has a big page talking about PHP object oriented programming and how `$this` behaves depending on context. 
 https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Great explanation. Just would like to add that $this can be treated as pseudo object/variable that helps access the properties of the current class.

Answer (score 18):

I know its old question, anyway another exact explanation about **$this**. **$this** is mainly used to refer properties of a class.

Example:

```
Class A
{
   public $myname;    //this is a member variable of this class

function callme() {
    $myname = 'function variable';
    $this->myname = 'Member variable';
    echo $myname;                  //prints function variable
    echo $this->myname;              //prints member variable
   }
}
```

output:

```
function variable

member variable
```

Answer (score 9):

It is the way to reference an instance of a class from within itself, the same as many other object oriented languages.

From the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> The pseudo-variable $this is available
> when a method is called from within an
> object context. $this is a reference
> to the calling object (usually the
> object to which the method belongs,
> but possibly another object, if the
> method is called statically from the
> context of a secondary object).

Answer (score 7):

Lets see what happens if we won't use $this and try to have instance variables and 
constructor arguments with the same name with the following code snippet

```
<?php

class Student {
    public $name;

    function __construct( $name ) {
        $name = $name;
    }
};

$tom = new Student('Tom');
echo $tom->name;

?>
```

It echos nothing but

```
<?php

class Student {
    public $name;

    function __construct( $name ) {
        $this->name = $name; // Using 'this' to access the student's name
    }
};

$tom = new Student('Tom');
echo $tom->name;

?>
```

this echoes 'Tom'

Comment: Your code snippets are both exactly the same, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Demento: yes. I fixed it, using `$this` in the second constructor.

Comment: Would you mind to explain why name = $name wont allow me to access the student's name? It's don't make sense to me.

Comment: Mario, it's because of scope. inside the function `$name` is Tom, but outside the function, it doesn't have any value, because its scope is limited to that of the function.

Answer (score 4):

when you create a class you have (in many cases) instance variables and methods (aka. functions).  $this accesses those instance variables so that your functions can take those variables and do what they need to do whatever you want with them.

another version of meder's example:

```
class Person {

    protected $name;  //can't be accessed from outside the class

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
// this line creates an instance of the class Person setting "Jack" as $name.  
// __construct() gets executed when you declare it within the class.
$jack = new Person("Jack"); 

echo $jack->getName();

Output:

Jack
```

Answer (score 3):

`$this` is [a reference to the calling object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

Answer (score 3):

This is long detailed explanation. I hope this will help the beginners. I will make it very simple.

First, let's create a class

```
<?php 

class Class1
{
    
}
```

You can omit the php closing tag `?>` if you are using php code only.

Now let's add properties and a method inside `Class1`.

```
<?php 

class Class1
{
    public $property1 = "I am property 1";
    public $property2 = "I am property 2";

    public function Method1()
    {
        return "I am Method 1";
    }
}
```

The property is just a simple variable , but we give it the name property cuz its inside a class.

The method is just a simple function , but we say method cuz its also inside a class.

The `public` keyword mean that the method or a property can be accessed anywhere in the script.

Now, how we can use the properties and the method inside `Class1` ?

The answer is creating an instance or an object, think of an object as a copy of the class.

```
<?php 

class Class1
{
    public $property1 = "I am property 1";
    public $property2 = "I am property 2";

    public function Method1()
    {
        return "I am Method 1";
    }
}

$object1 = new Class1;
var_dump($object1);
```

We created an object, which is `$object1` , which is a copy of `Class1` with all its contents. And we dumped all the contents of `$object1` using `var_dump()` .

This will give you

```
object(Class1)#1 (2) { ["property1"]=> string(15) "I am property 1" ["property2"]=> string(15) "I am property 2" }
```

So all the contents of `Class1` are in `$object1` , except `Method1` , i don't know why methods doesn't show while dumping objects.

Now what if we want to access `$property1` only. Its simple , we do `var_dump($object1->property1);` , we just added `->property1` , we pointed to it.

we can also access `Method1()` , we do `var_dump($object1->Method1());`.

Now suppose i want to access `$property1` from inside `Method1()` , i will do this

```
<?php 

class Class1
{
    public $property1 = "I am property 1";
    public $property2 = "I am property 2";

    public function Method1()
    {   
        $object2 = new Class1;
        return $object2->property1;
    }
}

$object1 = new Class1;
var_dump($object1->Method1());
```

we created `$object2 = new Class1;` which is a new copy of `Class1` or we can say an instance. Then we pointed to `property1` from `$object2`

```
return $object2->property1;
```

This will print `string(15) "I am property 1"` in the browser.

Now instead of doing this inside `Method1()`

```
$object2 = new Class1;
return $object2->property1;
```

We do this

```
return $this->property1;
```

The `$this` object is used inside the class to refer to the class itself.

It is an alternative for creating new object and then returning it like this

```
$object2 = new Class1;
return $object2->property1;
```

Another example

```
<?php 

class Class1
{
    public $property1 = 119;
    public $property2 = 666;
    public $result;

    public function Method1()
    {   
        $this->result = $this->property1 + $this->property2;
        return $this->result;
    }
}

$object1 = new Class1;
var_dump($object1->Method1());
```

We created 2 properties containing integers and then we added them and put the result in `$this->result`.

Do not forget that

`$this->property1` = `$property1` = `119`

they have that same value .. etc

I hope that explains the idea.

This series of videos will help you a lot in OOP

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLe30vg_FG4OSEHH6bRF8FrA7wmoAMUZLv

Answer (score 2):

$this is a special variable and it refers to the same object ie. itself.

it actually refer instance of current class

here is an example which will clear the above statement

```
<?php
 class Books {
  /* Member variables */
  var $price;
  var $title;

  /* Member functions */
  function setPrice($par){
     $this->price = $par;
  }

  function getPrice(){
     echo $this->price ."<br/>";
  }

  function setTitle($par){
     $this->title = $par;
  }

  function getTitle(){
     echo $this->title ." <br/>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: please elaborate it little more

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the instance of the current class, as **meder** said.

See the [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php). It's explained under the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, **this** keyword is used inside a class, generally with in the member functions to access non-static members of a class(variables or functions) for the current object.

1. this keyword should be preceded with a $ symbol.
2. In case of this operator, we use the -> symbol.
3. Whereas, $this will refer the member variables and function for a particular instance.

Let's take an example to understand the usage of $this.

```
<?php
class Hero {
    // first name of hero
    private $name;
    
    // public function to set value for name (setter method)
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    
    // public function to get value of name (getter method)
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

// creating class object
$stark = new Hero();

// calling the public function to set fname
$stark->setName("IRON MAN");

// getting the value of the name variable
echo "I Am " . $stark->getName();
?>
```

> OUTPUT:
> I am IRON MAN

NOTE:
A static variable acts as a global variable and is shared among all the objects of the class. A non-static variables are specific to instance object in which they are created.