# what is "$this" in php?

Tags: php, cakephp, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)

I know this is extremely basic. I am watching tutorials on YouTube about CakePHP and PHP and all of them keep using "$this", but none of them actually say what it is or what it is used for. I think it is a variable, but what does it contain, and why do all of the functions have to be run from it? Is it the current class? I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this) that "$this" is different from self though, so I am not sure if this is the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if used in a class, `$this` refers to the object that it's in.

Comment: made it so simle..less is more!!!

Answer (score 4):

$this refers to the instance of the class (a.k.a. object). self is more or less the same, but for static classes.

Comment: class is not also known as object, an object is a class in it's initiated form.

Comment: @RobertPitt sure thing - wanted to take it easy for someone that does not seem to be familiar with OOP in PHP

Comment: It's just incorrect regardless of the OP's Level

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read http://php.net/oop in particular this section http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

> The pseudo-variable $this is available
>   when a method is called from within an
>   object context. $this is a reference
>   to the calling object (usually the
>   object to which the method belongs,
>   but possibly another object, if the
>   method is called statically from the
>   context of a secondary object).