# What is $this keyword meant for?

Tags: php, oop, this

Please explain me that for what `$this` and `->` stands for...lets take the example of following code...

```
$this->convertNamesToCaptions($order, $formId)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 15):

$this refers to the current object

Manual says:

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

Little example:

```
class Test
{
    private $var;

    public function func()
    {
        $this->var = 1;
        return $this->var;
    }
}

$obj = new Test();

$obj->func();
```

Answer (score 5):

`$this` is reference to current object while inside that objects code.

You'll find more information in [PHP OOP basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Answer (score 5):

So, simply :

- `$this` refers to current object instance
- `->` indicates that the part on the right is a method of an object

In other words :

`$this->doSth()` means : run method `doSth` of the same object.

Answer (score 2):

`$this` hold the reference of the selected object in use, `->` is an operator used to assign a method or property to an object reference.

Answer (score 2):

I think this page say's it all: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

"The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object)."

in few words **it's the calling object**.

Answer (score 0):

$this is a pointer which points to the current object and -> is an operator used to assign value to an object on right hand side.