# Can anyone tell me the difference between $this keyword

Tags: php

What is the use of $this keyword? Output for both cases are same then why should we need to use $this keyword. And where $this keyword is used .

```
<?php
 class Test
 {
  private $var;
  public function func1()
   {
    $this->var = 1;     
    return $this->var;
   }
  public function func2()
  {
    $var = 2;       
    return $var;
  }
}

$obj = new Test();

echo $obj->func1();
echo $obj ->func2();

?>
```

Output for both cases 12 and 12.

Comment: $this refers to the current object

Comment: [Essential reading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is $this keyword meant for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974804/what-is-this-keyword-meant-for) or [How to explain 'this' keyword in a best and simple way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094052/how-to-explain-this-keyword-in-a-best-and-simple-way)

Comment: In your method `func2()`, `$var` is locally scoped, so it only exists inside `func2()` and can't be accessed by any other methods in your class. In method `func1()` you're referencing the class property `$var` by using `$this->var`.... class properties are available to any method in the class

Answer (score 1):

**$this refers to the current objec**

$this->var = 1;

the $object->var value has changed to 1.

---

$var = 2;

the $object->var not changed.

```html
 class Test
 {
  public $var = 0;
  public function func1()
   {
    $this->var = 1;     
    return $this->var;
   }
  public function func2()
  {
    $var = 2;       
    return $var;
  }
}

$obj = new Test();

echo "By default $obj->var is : ".$obj->var;
$obj->func1();
echo "<hr />By func1 $obj->var change to : ".$obj->var;
$obj->func2();
echo "<hr />By func2 $obj->var still is : ".$obj->var;
exit;
```

The output

```html
By default $obj->var is : 0
By func1 $obj->var change to : 1
By func2 $obj->var still is : 1
```

Comment: `$var` is not an object. its a property ($this->var), or a variable ($var)

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference to the current object, it's most commonly used in object oriented code .

it is actually refering instance of current class.

Comment: Within a function always it will refer to current obj. Are you saying global variable vs local variable.

Comment: yes, its usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object only if the method is called staticaly  from the context of a secondary object

Answer (score 0):

In very general terms, we can say that $this is used to reference the current object, you can got a good explanation here [What is $this keyword meant for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974804/what-is-this-keyword-meant-for) or [How to explain 'this' keyword in a best and simple way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094052/how-to-explain-this-keyword-in-a-best-and-simple-way)