# How to use a variable to call a function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, variables

is it possible to do something like this in php?

$this->getUser$number();

I can't find if there's somekinda syntax to make this possible.

Regards

Comment: Yes, inside a class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
$this->{"getUser".$number}();
```

Of course you can use the same syntax outside a method:

```
$obj = new Something();
$obj->{"getUser".$number}();
```

That said, code like this is a bad smell and should be avoided. For example, it's better to make the `getUser` method accept an argument and call it like this:

```
$this->getUser($number);
```

This way the call site remains "sane", while the implementation of `getUser` can use `$number` as e.g. an index into an array and also achieve much better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

It's called OOP programming, it is used in most likely any big system. It is also used alot in a MVC application. Read more about OOP programming here; http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.php

These expression can also be used like this;

```
$this->$name
```

or even further to;

```
$this->name =& $name
$this->name = $${val}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use symbol `$` as name of function. But on the other hand `$this->getUserNumber();` you can use inside some class.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this as

```
$number = "10";
$func = "getUser".$number ;
$this->$func();
```

it'll call some function named

> getUser10();

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do this:

```
   $methodName = 'getUser' . $number;
   $this->$methodName();
```