# Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, function, class, object

This code is in my `user.php` file

```
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

        private $_db;

        function __construct($db){
            parent::__construct();

            $this->_db = $db;
        }

        private function get_user_hash($email){ 

            try {
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = :email AND active="Yes" ');
                $stmt->execute(array('email' => $email));

                $row = $stmt->fetch();
                return $row['password'];

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
            }
        }

        public function login($email,$password){

            $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($email);

            if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                return true;
            }   
        }

        public function logout(){
            session_destroy();
        }

        public function is_logged_in(){
            if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
                return true;
            }       
        }
    }
```

And this code is part of my `login.php` file

```
function login($email,$password){

$hashed = $this->get_user_hash($email);  <--the error is in this line

if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    return true;
}
```

I honestly don't know what to do, I'm still learning these kinds of things & I'm not really good with classes and objects that's why I'm asking everyone to help me fix this problem.

Comment: What issue you are having?

Comment: @MTahir I've fixed the problem I'm asking earlier. but my problem now is "Call to a member function prepare() on null". Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
$hashed = $this->get_user_hash($email);  <--the error is in this line
```

With

```
$user = new User($db);
$hashed = $user->get_user_hash($email);
```

You can not use this outside a class. You can learn more about $this in php in following SO post.
[What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)

Comment: The error changed to "Call to private method User::get_user_hash() from context" Do you know how to fix it? And thanks :)

Comment: You need to declare method as public if want to access outside function. remove `private` keyword from function definition.

Comment: And now it changed to "Call to a member function prepare() on null" well I don't know what this means. Sorry, I'm really new to this.

Comment: SO can't replace a good tutorial. Your questions are so basic that it's obivous that a tutorial and basic training on PHP's classes is what you need. Fixing errors one by one through asking here isn't going to help you.

Comment: @EdRyanEstrella your $db object has not been passed correctly.