# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in (Fatal error)

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in G:\xampp\htdocs\live\Billing Suryas\model\DBConfig.php on line 28

```
<?php
    class Database
    {   
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $db_name = "new_suryas1";
        private $username = "root";
        private $password = "";
        public $conn;
        public function dbConnection()
        {
            $this->conn = NULL;    
            try
            {
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
            }
            catch(PDOException $exception)
            {
                echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
            }

            return $conn;
        }
        public function login($usname,$uspswd)
        {
            try
            {
                $stmt =$conn->prepare("select * from users where user_name=:uname and password=:paswrd and permission='0' and delet='0'");
                $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$usname, ':paswrd'=>$uspswd));
                $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
                {
                    if(password_verify($uspswd, $userRow['password']))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $exception)
            {
                echo $exception->getMessage();
            }
        }

    }
    ?>
```

This is my **DBConfig.php**

I can't find what is the error in my code

anyone help me please...

Comment: It seems to me `$conn` isn't a db connection. In other words... Making a connection to the database failed. The value of `$conn` is false then.

Answer (score 1):

You write a class with these properties:

```
class Database
{   
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "new_suryas1";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;
```

Inside a class method, variable scope is same as functions: external variables are not accessible.

To access to class properties inside a class method you have to use `$this`:

```
$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

(...)

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("select * from users where user_name=:uname and password=:paswrd and permission='0' and delet='0'");
```

---

- Read more about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
- Read more about [What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1523484/3294262)

Comment: The code must be work. Edit question adding the code in which you call the Database Class.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store the DB connection handle in a variable `$conn`. But that is just a local variable, *not* the class property `$conn`. To use the later you have to access it is `$this->conn`.

So your connection method should be something like

```
public function dbConnection()
{
    try {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    } catch(PDOException $exception) {
        echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Given that you now can use `$this->conn` in other functions

```
public function login($usname, $uspswd)
{
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("select * from users where user_name=:uname and password=:paswrd and permission='0' and delet='0'");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$usname, ':paswrd'=>$uspswd));
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
            if(password_verify($uspswd, $userRow['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch(PDOException $exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
```

In other words: using `$conn` instead of `$this->conn` does *not* refer to the objects property `$conn`, but a local variable `$conn` in the methods. But local variables are *not* persistent. So once you leave the method `dbConnection()` and try to reuse that variable by picking the same name in `login()`, the identifier `$conn` actually refers to two *different* local variables. Which of course means that it does not hold any value in the `login()` method which leads to the error you receive.

There are other approaches to this like "injecting the connection object" into your methods. But the above is a clean and usually preferred approach.

Comment: OK, in that case it might be that your database connection simply fails (whyever). Your code does not contain any error detection or handling for such incident which is why it is not detected. So I suggest you 1. check in your http servers error log file what the problem is (as a php developer you _always_ have to monitor that file) and you then add error detection and handling to your code.