# Explanation of $this variable usage in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I can't quite understand the OOP here. What I believe is that $this or this can be used to point to the current instance of the class and has access to all non-static members. But then what is happening here:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate()
}
```

This code is from the **controller class of the Laravel framework**. I can have access to validate() method but the problem is, its not in the current class and even if its being inherited from the base or parent class, I shouldn't be able to access it through $this variable.

And later in the code I was able to use my Model like this:

```
$post = new Post;
```

Why did I call the Model Post class and not the constructor of that class?

Comment: `$this` works through the inheritance tree, with access to public or protected methods in parents, grandparents, great-grandparents, etc; so why do you believe `and even if its being inherited from the base or parent class, I shouldn't be able to access it through $this variable.`?

Comment: Check this link, it might be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php

Comment: As for `$post = new Post;`.... the constructor is called automagically when you instantiate a class

Answer (score 5):

> What I believe is that $this or this can be used to point to the
>   current instance of the class and has access to all non-static
>   members.

That is correct.

> I can have access to validate() method but the problem is, its not in
>   the current class and even if its being inherited from the base or
>   parent class, I shouldn't be able to access it through $this variable.

This is wrong.

The `validate` method comes from a `trait` (found in `Laravel\Lumen\Routing\ProvidesConvenienceMethods`). If a controller uses the trait, and you extend the controller - you inherited the methods from this "base" class.