# Not quite understanding how to use a constructor it seems

Tags: php, oop

I am making a minor CMS for specific use at my current job, and I want to do it right... hence OOP.

For this I want to make a database connection class that I can use in my other classes when I need to make database queries. However, for some reason, I keep being stopped at the same point, because I don't seem to be able to get the connection string into my classes.

Whatever changes I make, I end up with "undefined... " something every time.

**File - databaseManagement.class.php:**

```
class database {
private $user;
private $pass;
private $db;
private $serv;
private $type;
private $dsn;
private $sqlsrvString;
private $charset;
private $dbIni;
private $options;
public $connectionInfo;
public $dbConn;

public function __construct() {
    $this->dbIni = parse_ini_file('settings/database.ini.php');

// ... assign values to individual variables based on values in the database.ini.php file.
    $this->user = $this->dbIni['user'];
    $this->pass = $this->dbIni['pass'];
    $this->db = $this->dbIni['db'];
    $this->serv = $this->dbIni['serv'];
    $this->type = $this->dbIni['type'];
    $this->charset = $this->dbIni['charset'];
    
    $this->connectionInfo = array( 
        "Database"=>$this->db, 
        "UID"=>$this->user, 
        "PWD"=>$this->pass
    );

}

public function dbConnect() {
    $this->dbConn = sqlsrv_connect($this->serv, $this->connectionInfo);
}
```

**File - smallInfo.class.php**

```
class smallInfo {
function __construct() {
    $initDB = new database();
    $initDB->dbConnect();
    
    var_dump($initDB);
}

function showDkProgress(){
    echo "<hr />";
    print_r($initDB->dbConn);
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Now the var_dump() in smallInfo constructor returns all the expected values, including those of $dbConn, however, I can't seem to access $dbConn in *showDkProgress()* for use in queries.

Comment: What does your `print_r($initDB->dbConn)` call show?

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: initDB in asfo\modules\smallInfo\smallInfo.class.php on line 12
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'dbConn' of non-object in asfo\modules\smallInfo\smallInfo.class.php on line 12

Comment: Just an aside - it may be worth reading https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/ for some coding standards.  It's a good guide to some basic things which help code readability.

Comment: declare `$initDB` as a property first, then access it as `$this->initDB`, you already got it on the first class, just follow the same suit

Comment: define a property `$dbConn` in class SmallInfo. use `$this->dbConn = $initDB->dbConnect();` in your constructor - now you can access your dbConn from other methods in your class using `$this->dbConn`

Comment: for accessing variable property in inside your class you will have to declare it after class name. Then you will initialize it. After that you can easily access through $this keyword

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Constructor, $this keyword, and controller class in PHP/Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274735/understanding-constructor-this-keyword-and-controller-class-in-php-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Constructors does not set variables (e.g. `$variableName`) as object attributes. You have to explicitly assign it with `$this->variableName` assignment.
2. Unlike Java, the OOP implementation in PHP does not automatically alias attributes. The variable `$variableName` in a method does not automatically equal to `$this->variableName`.

So:

```php
class smallInfo {
  function __construct() {
    $this->initDB = new database();
    $this->initDB->dbConnect();
    var_dump($this->initDB);
  }

  function showDkProgress(){
    echo "<hr />";
    print_r($this->initDB->dbConn);
    echo "<hr />";
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow... This is so dumb (for me)... I already tried the     "print_r($this->initDB->dbConn);" solution but never once considered that $this-> was also required for the constructer...

So obvious, but still missed it... Thanks.

Comment: For first beginners, it's easy to confuse attributes and local variables. Also different language has different implementation on the same concept. Your code manner (not the exact syntax) can probably run smoothly in Java. PHP requires you to be a little bit more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

In your `smallinfo` class, `initDB` is a **local** variable inside the constructor. It doesn't exists outside the constructor.

Thus, accessing an undefined variable named `initDB` in `showDkProgress` yields an error.

You need to make `initDB` a *field*.

```php
class smallInfo {

    private $initDB;

    function __construct() {
        $this->initDB = new database();
        $this->initDB->dbConnect();
    
        var_dump($this->initDB);
    }

    function showDkProgress(){
        echo "<hr />";
        print_r($this->initDB->dbConn);
        echo "<hr />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function showDkProgress() is unable to get it since it is only local variable in constructor.
If you embed $initDB in class you should add field for it.

so try eg:

```
class smallInfo {

  public $initDB;

  function __construct() {
    $this->initDB = new database();
    $this->initDB->dbConnect();

  function showDkProgress(){
    $si = new smallInfo();
    echo "<hr />";
    print_r($this->initDB->dbConn);
    echo "<hr />";
}
```