# Why am I getting NULL when I try to initiate a connection?

Tags: php

I have a class with global `$connection` but when I try to access it I am getting NULL. As you can see if i try to access within the constructor I do not get NULL. But from `getConnection()` I am getting NULL.

```
class DatabaseManipulation
{
    private $connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        global $connection;
        $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db");
        $result = $connection->query("select * from user");

        print_r($result); //I get an array
    }

    function getConnection(){
        global $connection;
        var_dump($connection); // I get -> object(DatabaseManipulation)#1 (1) { ["connection":"DatabaseManipulation":private]=> NULL } NULL 
    }

}
```

Same thing happens when I instantiate an object `$connection = new DatabaseManipulation();`. Am I doing something wrong? I want this to be done in OO way. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using OO PHP not procedural. So change it to:

```
$this->connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db");;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want this to be done in OO way.

Then stop using `global`. You don't want to refer to a global state when you're in a class. A quick look to [The Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) and you will find that a pseudo-variable `$this` is available inside your object.

```
class DatabaseManipulation
{
    private $connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db");
    }

    function getConnection(){
        var_dump($this->connection);
    }
}
```

More about it:

1. [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)
2. [What does the variable $this mean
   in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)

Comment: I am still getting error : Notice: Undefined variable: connection in....

Comment: where's your code? you should refer to `connection` using `$this`: `$this->connection->query("select * from user");`

Comment: Did you read the code above? Also, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php

Comment: Then change your code accordingly.  Be aware that `$this->$connection` !== `$this->connection`