# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function - have to use $this

Tags: php, function, scope, fatal-error

Here is my code:

```
<?php

public function __construct() {
    getUsername();
}

public function getUsername() {
    //blah blah blah

    return "bobby";
}

?>
```

It does not work and it says this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function...

but if I call the function in my constructor like this: `$this->getUsername();` it works. Why is that the case?

Comment: `getUsername()` is a method, not a function.

Comment: `$this->nameOfFunction()`, when they are in a class, they are called Methods.

Comment: read this answer to understand difference between method and function.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It cannot identify your method. We have to tell it to use `getUsername()` method which is in this class like this `$this->getUsername();` 
`$this->` is for find in this class.
read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)