# Does PHP have keyword or feature that shortens repetition like jquery $(this)?

Tags: php, jquery

Does PHP have keyword or feature that shortens code and repetition like jquery $(this)?

For example

```
// How to avoid typing same variable twice
echo isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : '';
```

In Jquery

```
<script>
    // Avoid typing $("#button-element") again
    $("#button-element").click(function() {
        $(this).css("border-color", "#000");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But PHP is not built off ECMAScript...? If you want to avoid repetition, use the [null coalesce operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary), i.e. `echo $_POST['foo'] ?? '';`, but that's only in PHP 7.

Comment: your `this` right now, is treated as a constant, just so you know "this" ;-) You're probably looking for an (PHP) OOP `$this` but it's hard to say really what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Have you tried to research your question before asking it on here? I'm sure something would be on google.... if not then that's also a sign of "no". I don't really understand what you wish to achieve or the real purpose...

Comment: I searched stackoverflow for a similar question, no luck.

Comment: Are you looking for the  operator? `?:`

Comment: @Fred -ii- Asking to see if there is a shorter way of accessing the same variable, instead of typing the same variable over again.

Comment: In PHP7 you can `echo $_POST['foo'] ?? 'bar';`. Way cooler. For google: `Null coalescing operator`

Comment: @Goldbug The question is unclear for me, sorry. See if the answer(s) given solves it.

Comment: `$var = "foo"; echo isset($_POST['foo']) ? $var : '';`  maybe? Is that what you're after?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php#1523484 See there!

Comment: You appear to have a significantly distorted understanding of the `this` variable in JavaScript. You should probably read quite a bit on it, at a minimum, [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Answer (score 2):

No. And that code wouldn't work in JS either.

In JS, `this` is -- roughly speaking -- the object that the current function was called as a method on. It is not "the last thing I mentioned". The JS equivalent of your second code:

```
_POST['foo'] ? this : ''
```

would return an object if `_POST['foo']` were set. It would not return the value of `_POST['foo']`.

There is no variable like the one you're looking for in *any* language I've ever used.

Comment: "the object that the current function was called as a method on" It's same in PHP if I'm not wrong

Comment: @btc4cash PHP's `$this` is roughly similar to JS `this`, but the JS `this` has a lot of weird edge cases which don't apply to PHP.

Answer (score -1):

of course it does! you need to construct this across a class.
It works about the same as in javascript ES6 class.

```
$number = 4;
$This = new demoThis($number);
$This->multiplyThis(4);

class demoThis {

private $number;
private $factor;
public $result;

    public function __construct($number) {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    function multiplyThis($factor) {
        $this->factor = $factor;
        $this->result = $this->number * $this->factor;
        return $this->result;
    }
}

echo isset($_POST['foo']) ? $This->result : '';
```