# laravel getTable in parent class

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and I have model class

```
class Apartment extends Property
{
    protected $table = 'apartments';
}
```

and parent class

```
abstract class Property extends Model
{
   
    protected $table = '';

    public function doSomthing ()
    {
        echo $table = $this->getTable(); //$this->table
    }
}
```

how I can read $table (apartments) or get table name in parent class

$this->getTable(); and $this->table and self::$table not work

Comment: Aside from the fact that that's not a "model", what's the `var_dump($this)` ?

Comment: <<Using $this when not in object context>>

Comment: Well .. that would indicate that you placed that code in the wrong part. You maybe should start by understanding, [what `$this` actually is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1523484/727208).

Answer (score -1):

```
class Apartment extends Property
{
    protected $table = 'apartments';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct($this->table);
    }
}

abstract class Property extends Model
{

    protected $table = '';

    function __construct($var)
    {
        $this->table = $var; //$this->table should be 'apartments'

    }

}
```

Comment: Non-static method App\Property ::doSomthing () should not be called statically

Comment: and after i add "static" to (public static function doSomething) i got <<Using $this when not in object context>>

Comment: 1. doSomthing can be called as usual like $this->doSomthing();
2. if doSomthing has to be a static function, try to pass $this->table as an argument to doSomthing($table){...}, You can not use $this inside a static function

Comment: yes i already made this ( doSomthing($table) )
but i asked for a better solution
and way big thanks to u