# Uncaught Error: Using $this

Tags: php, sql

I've seen other posts about this but I just can't understand them, what is the solution here, can you guys show me? Please. Static or not static? What does it mean? Is this the problem?

Db connection code:-

```
<?php 
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', ''); 
define('DB_DATABASE', 'not telling'); 
class DB_con { 
    public $connection; 
    function __construct(){ 
        $this->connection = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE); 
        if ($this->connection->connect_error) 
            die('Database error -> ' . $this->connection->connect_error); 
    } 
    function ret_obj(){ 
        return $this->connection; 
    } 
}
```

Code for fetching records:-

```
<?php

$role_id = (isset($_SESSION['role_id']) ? $_SESSION['role_id'] : 4) ;

$query = "
   SELECT rights_codename FROM permissions 
   INNER JOIN roles_and_permissions ON fk_permissions_id = permissions_id
   WHERE fk_role_id = $role_id
   ";

$_SESSION['permissions'] = array();
$result = $this->db->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

   array_push($_SESSION['permissions'], $row['permissions_cname']);

 //  $_SESSION['permissions'][] = $row['permissions_cname'];

}
if(in_array('admin_rediger_bruger',$_SESSION['permissions'])){
}

?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\R_L_E\login.php:30 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\R_L_E\login.php on line 30

Comment: Where's your SQL connection?

Comment: [What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)

Comment: <?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'not telling');

class DB_con {
 public $connection;
 function __construct(){
  $this->connection = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
  
  if ($this->connection->connect_error) die('Database error -> ' . $this->connection->connect_error);
  
 }
 
 function ret_obj(){
  return $this->connection;
 }

}

Comment: it dont like this line: $result = $this->db->query($query);

Comment: Where is that being called in your code?

Comment: you mean this? sorry i am not that good to programming

class User{
  protected $db;
  public function __construct(){
   $this->db = new DB_con();
   $this->db = $this->db->ret_obj();
  }

Answer (score 1):

In lay man terms,  `$this` is when you are referencing a non static function in a class.  What you can do is create a new instance of the database class and then use that variable created during instantiation to access the member functions of that class

Do this

```
$conn = new DB_con();//instantiate the class.add this at the very top of login.php
$conn->connection->query('your sql stuff');//replace the $this->db->query($query) with this line
```

You can access the `connection` property as it is declared as public in your class

Also do not forget to include the `DB_con file`

Comment: dont really work sorry i am noob> hope this help

https://postimg.org/gallery/39s2qs54c/

Comment: Instantiate the class at the top of login.php.. Then replace the `$this` query with the second line of code I wrote

Comment: Check out the updated answer. Read the comments I added

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is a variable that refers to "the current object" *when you're running code inside that object*. That means, when you write this:

```
class AClass {
    public function foo() {
        var_dump($this);
    }
}
$my_object = new AClass;
$my_object->foo();
```

Then `$this` is the same as `$my_object` during the execution of the `foo()` function. You can think of it like an extra parameter to the function, once you leave that function it won't exist any more.

So when you write this:

```
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

You need to be inside some method which has been called on a particular object, so that there is an object for `$this` to refer to. If you're in global code, or a function that's not part of a class, or a static method, there is no "current object", so `$this` doesn't exist.

In your case, you're trying to get to some instance of a DB connection object. That means somewhere in your code you need to have created that object, and assigned it to a variable, then you can reference that variable. You can call that variable whatever you like, but you can't call it `$this`, because that's a reserved name.

Your `DB_Con` class doesn't have a `query()` method, so it looks like you want to get the MySQLi object out first, and then call the method on that.

So you would write something like:

```
 $my_db_connection = new DB_Con;
 $mysqli_connection = $my_db_connection->connection;
 // or: $mysqli_connection = $my_db_connection->ret_obj();
 $result = $mysqli_connection->query($query);
```

Or more concisely:

```
 $my_db_connection = new DB_Con;
 $result = $my_db_connection->connection->query($query);
 // or: $result = $my_db_connection->ret_obj()->query($query);
```

Comment: https://postimg.org/gallery/39s2qs54c/

i change: $this->db = new DB_con(); out with $my_db_connection = new DB_Con;

and $result = $this->db->query($query);
out with $result = $my_db_connection->connection->query($query);?

the first one is in class.user file with a link to database
the second line is in login with a link to class.user file

Comment: @DenizBircan Sorry, I don't have time to write your code for you. You'll need to try things out and see if they work, and try not to copy and paste examples without understanding *why* the code looks that way. Start simple, understand the principles, and work your way up.