# slim routing and controller (how this __call function is calling from route and why $this->request is using insted of $request=)

Tags: php, oop, call, slim, magic-function

guys please help me to understand these code

in picture 1 router is calling with info method

as you can see in AccountController there is already info() is present then why __call() this magic function is calling

and what are these parameters is $this->request ,$this->response

we can save all data like

$request = $args[0]; $response = $args[1]; $attributes = $args[2];

why $this-> syntex is use 
what is the meaning of this line $this->$name();

Router.php

```
<?php

$app->get('/account', '\App\Controller\AccountController:info');

?>
```

AccountController.php

```
<?php
/**
 * AccountController
 * @package Controllers
 */
namespace App\Controller;


final class AccountController extends \App\Core\Controller
{

    protected function info()
    {

        echo $this->client_id;

    }
}
```

Controller.php

```
 <?php

namespace App\Core;


 class Controller
{


  public function __call($name,$args) { //line 25
        //echo "Call method : ".$name;
        $this->request = $args[0];
        $this->response = $args[1];
        $this->attributes = $args[2];

        //print_r($this->attributes);
        $this->client_id = $this->request->getAttribute("client_id");



              $this->$name();

    }

}


?>
```

Comment: Hi Kershav - can you edit your question to include code snippets, not images? It makes your question more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Router.php called your `info()` method on AccountController.php
But your method is protected and `info()` method not accessible out of the class
so `__call()` magic method has been called with `$name` and `$args` parameters.

$name => value is method name. "info".
$args => value array of response,request,attributes

`$this` => It's a reference to the current object, it's most commonly used in the object-oriented code.
[What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)

`request`,`response`,`attributes`,`client_id` they are variables of the controller class and accessible on each method of controller class children. like `$this->client_id` in your `AccountController` class.

```
    $this->request = $args[0];
    $this->response = $args[1];
    $this->attributes = $args[2];
    $this->client_id = $this->request->getAttribute("client_id");
```

`$this->$name();` This dymnaic way for call the methods.

[PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 0):

$this refers to itself and `$this->$name();`

will calling method to your function that received as `$name in __call()` function