# What do a reference of a method do?

Tags: php, reference

What do this reference symbol `(&)` do in `&methodName()` method?

Is it necessary?

Is this called a `reference by method`?

```
class TestClass
{
    private $value;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->value = 5;
    }
    public function &methodName(){
        return $this->value;
    }
}
echo (new TestClass())->methodName();  //Outputs 5;
```

Comment: It's a reference to the current object, it's most commonly used in object oriented code. Show this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the method returns a reference. If you then assign that to a reference variable outside the method, updating the variable will update the property.

```
class TestClass
{
    private $value;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->value = 5;
    }
    public function &refMethod(){
        return $this->value;
    }
    public function valueMethod() {
        return $this->value;
    }
    public function printValue() {
        echo $this->value . "<br>";
    }
}
$c = new TestClass();
$var1 = &$c->valueMethod();
$var1 = 10;
$c->printValue(); // prints 5
$var = &$c->refMethod();
$var = 20;
$c->printValue(); // prints 20
```