# Key-Value array syntax in PHP

Tags: php

I've written some PHP code using PDO. I'm new at PHP syntax, so I'm following the PHP documentation. I'm getting a syntax error on the $params = array(... statement. Perhaps the syntax issue is the reference to the global variables, but that's the reference I found in the PHP documentation.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

/*
    Sets up a PDO object for the ResDatLog table
*/

class Resdatalog
{  
    // database connection and table name
    private $_conn;
    private $_table_name = "ResDataLog";

    // object properties
    public $ID;
    public $Location = null;
    public $Temperature;
    public $Humidity;
    public $Pressure;
    public $RecDate;
    public $AmbientTemp;
    public $AmbientHum;
    public $AmbientPressure;

    /* 
        constructor with $db as database connection
    */
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    /* 
        Reads all columns of the entire table ($table_name)
    */
    function read() 
    {
        // select all query
        $query = "SELECT *
                FROM
                " . $this->table_name . "
                ORDER BY 
                    id DESC";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }
    function insert()
    {
        // insert a new row into the table_name table
        $sql = 'INSERT Location, Temperature, Humidity, Pressure, RecDate,
         AmbientTemp, AmbientHum, AmbientPressure into '
         . $this->table_name . 
         ' VALUES (:Location,:Temperature, :Humidity, 
         :Pressure, :RecDate, :AmbientTemp, :AmbientHum, :AmbientPressure)';

        $sth = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

        $params = array(
            ':Location' => ResDataLog->Location,
            ':Temperature'=> ResDataLog->Temperature,
            ':Humidity'=> ResDataLog->Humidity,
            ':Pressure'=> ResDataLog->Pressure,
            ':RecDate'=> ResDataLog->RecDate,
            ':AmbientTemp'=> ResDataLog->AmbientTemp,
            ':AmbientHum'=> ResDataLog->AmbientHum,
            ':AmbientPressure'=> ResDataLog->AmbientPressure);


         Return($$sth->execute($params));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: where does ResDataLog come from? Show that code.

Comment: the function insert() is inside the ResDatLog class. So are the variables shown ($Location, et al). ResDataLog->Location refers to $Location, public  in the same class, but outside the scope of insert().

Comment: It should be `Resdatalog::Location`, same for all the elements. Notice also the capitalization "ResDataLog" is not correct.

Comment: It should not be `Resdatalog::Location` because it's not a static member!

Comment: OK, I fixed the syntax you mentioned (thank you so much...) but I continue to get (from VSCode) 
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ')'

Comment: Replace Resdatalog-> with [$this->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php) (don't use the double colons because the class properties aren't static). Also, you have an extraneous $ in `Return($$sth->execute($params));`

Comment: When I use $this->, do I use the dollar sign in front of the public variable? 
(in other words...$this->$Location, or $this->Location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `$this` as you are `inside` the class instead of using direct **class** name.

1. If you were `outside` of the class then you need to make an instance of `Resdatalog` and then access/assign values to the variables like below.

   ```
    $ResdatalogInstance = new Resdatalog;
    $ResdatalogInstance->Location="assign some values";
   ```
2. If it were `static` like `public static $Location;`, then you can do this way, `Resdatalog::$Location` or `self::$Location`.

   ```
   $params = array(
     ':Location' => $this->Location,
      ':Temperature'=> $this->Temperature,
     ':Humidity'=> $this->Humidity,
     ':Pressure'=> $this->Pressure,
     ':RecDate'=> $this->RecDate,
     ':AmbientTemp'=> $this->AmbientTemp,
     ':AmbientHum'=> $this->AmbientHum,
     ':AmbientPressure'=> $this->AmbientPressure
   ```

   );

Also you need to remove extra `$` sign from this line,

```
 return ($sth->execute($params));
        ^^
```

Comment: The next question by the OP will probably be about this line `Return($$sth->execute($params));`...

Comment: I used Always Sunny's code exactly, and it has no syntax error. I suspect this may be because I've put each parameter on separate lines in my code. Thank you Sunny!

Comment: @JimS-CLT glad it helps you somehow, sorry I couldn't format the code properly from my phone :(