# What does $this means?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What means $this in laravel?

For example:

```php
public function car() {
  return $this->hasOne('App\Car');
}
```

Can I use this for example too?

```php
public function car() {
  return $car->hasOne('App\Car');
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In this particular case `$this` refers to a Laravel Eloquent model where the `car()` method is located in. `$car→hasOne` cannot be used, because `$car` is undefined variable. Please refer to a basic OOP example stated in the comment above. `$this` is nothing more than just a reference to the class.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a laravel feature, but a PHP feature. Please read the following document [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Simply put, $this refers to the current instance of the object during runtime.