# Type: Error Message: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, rabbitmq, codeigniter-3, message-queue

i have an error in my code. I want to call the **get_mail()** function in the **index** function. This code is rabbitmq with phpcodeigniter consumer code, error message is:

Type: Error

Message: Class 'get_mail' not found

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\mail\application\controllers\Consumer.php

Line Number: 45

```
<?php 


defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    


require_once APPPATH.'../vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Exchange\AMQPExchangeType;
class Consumer extends CI_Controller {
public function index(){
     
    
    $host = "secret";
    $port = 5672;
    $user = "secret";
    $pass = "secret";
    $vhost = "secret";
    $exchange = 'router';
    $queue = 'mail';
    $consumerTag = 'consumer';

    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($host, $port, $user, $pass, $vhost);
    $channel = $connection->channel();

    $channel->queue_declare($queue, false, true, false, false);

    $channel->exchange_declare($exchange, AMQPExchangeType::DIRECT, false, true, false);

    $channel->queue_bind($queue, $exchange);
    function process_message($message)
    {

        $pesan = json_decode($message->body);
        $isi = $pesan->email;
        $this->get_mail();
        $message->ack();


    }

    $channel->basic_consume($queue, $consumerTag, false, false, false, false, 'process_message');
    function shutdown($channel, $connection)
    {
        $channel->close();
        $connection->close();
    }

    register_shutdown_function('shutdown', $channel, $connection);
    while ($channel ->is_consuming()) {
        $channel->wait();
    }
    
}

public function get_mail($isi){
    //this is function for send mail in codeigniter
}

   

  
    
   
    // Loop as long as the channel has callbacks registered
   
}

/* End of file Consumer.php */


?>
```

this is error message from php:
Type: Error

Message: Using $this when not in object context

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\mail\application\controllers\Consumer.php

Line Number: 45

Comment: what does [$this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php) mean...

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why do you put functions into functions?

Comment: Why you put some functions nexted on index function?

You will need create a new class with the function 'get_mail'... so you will call this class...

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, you need to create a separate object of the class to use get_email.
Problem is:
process_message is execute by Queue And The internal Queue class doesn't have get_email, that;s why you are getting the error - not found.

Possible Solution: create a Separate class for email and create the object whenever it is need, even in your method.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not support nested functions, so when you write code like this...

```php
class X {
    public function foo() {
        function bar() {
            echo "hello world";
            var_dump($this); // this will give an error
        }

        something_needing_a_callback('bar');
    }
}
```

...you are actually just declaring a *global* function called `bar`, and it has no relationship to class `X`; it is as though you'd written this (except that the function doesn't get declared until you run `foo`):

```php
class X {
    public function foo() {
         something_needing_a_callback('bar');
    }
}
function bar() {
    echo "hello world";
    var_dump($this); // $this has no meaning here, we are not inside a class
}
```

What you are probably looking for is [closures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), AKA anonymous functions, which *can* "capture" or "bind" variables from their surrounding scope, and automatically bind `$this`; so you could write this:

```php
class X {
     public function foo() {
          $myBarFunction = function() {
                echo "hello world";
                var_dump($this); // works :)
          }
          something_needing_a_callback($myBarFunction);
     }
}
```

Alternatively, you can write a named method on the class and use that as the callback [using the syntax for referencing callables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), but note that it needs to be public, since the function that will eventually call it is not inside the class:

```php
class X {
    public function foo() {
         something_needing_a_callback([$this, 'bar']);
    }

    public function bar() {
         echo "hello world";
         var_dump($this); // OK, because just an ordinary method
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can work out how to apply that to your actual code.