# Codeigniter 4, call a controller method in a seeder

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Morning guys,
I'm searching on how to call a function of a controller in my seeder file.

**Account Controller**

```
public function createCompte() {
    //generate an account number
        return $numcompte;
    }
}
```

**seeder**

```
public function run(){
    $compteController = new CompteController;
    $numcompte = $this->compteController->createCompte();
    $data_client = [ 
           //other data generate with faker
            'num_cmpte_client' => $numcompte ,
           
        ];
    $id_client = $this->db->table('client')->insert($tab);
 }
```

Comment: You are assigning the controller instance to a local variable `$compteController` but then you are calling his method `createCompte()` using another varibale that seems to be a property of the seeder `$this->compteController->createCompte()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [@Pippo in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76422912/codeigniter-4-call-a-controller-method-in-a-seeder?noredirect=1#comment134757885_76422912):

> You are assigning the controller instance to a local variable
> `$compteController` but then you are calling his method
> `createCompte()` using another varibale that seems to be a property of
> the seeder `$this->compteController->createCompte()`

So;

Instead of:❌

```php
$numcompte = $this->compteController->createCompte();
```

Use this:✅

```php
$numcompte = $compteController->createCompte();
```

Reference(s):

1. [What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)
2. [php.net: $this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class)